# PHP obtain root dir absolute path dynamically

Tags: php

I'm a newbie of php.

I would like to create a php config file where to set the absolute path of my project directory structure.
My config file is located in 'private/class' directory and it will be included in 'root' and private directory files.

Project directory structure is

```
class
img
photo
etc
private/class
private/photo
private/photo/thumb
private/etc
```

To get the absolute path where the file is located, I use magic php costants **DIR**,

```
define('MAINPATH', __DIR__ );
```

this show

```
/var/www/projectname/private/class
```

and this variable remains the same if I include the config file in the index.php or private/index.php , etc.

Now I have the problem of finding the other path starting from the main one. 
Usually I use realpath,  but in this case I do not think will go well. 
I tried in this way

```
define('PHOTOPATH', __DIR__ . '../photo');

define('PHOTOPATH', realpath ( __DIR__ . '../photo'));
```

these show

```
1 - /var/www/projectname/private/class../photo
2 - nothing
```

How could I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to append the PATH SEPARATOR (*/*) before appending the rest of the path.

```
define('PHOTOPATH', realpath ( __DIR__ . '/../photo'));
                                         ^
                                         |
                                         +- notice here the '/' is added
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].